# convergence/divergence $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{-n+1})^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am stuck with this series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{n}{-n+1})^n$. I used nth-root test, but the limit was $1$. Then I tried to think about it as $(-1)^n(\frac{n}{n-1})^n$ to use Leibniz, and I got $\lim (\frac{n}{n-1})^n \not = 0$. What else can I do?

Comment: If the terms don't tend to zero, then the series is divergent.

Comment: $-\frac{n}{n-1} = -\frac{n-1+1}{n-1} = -(1+\frac{1}{n-1})$.  Shift by one and adjust the limit for $\mathrm{e}$.

Comment: @EricTowers While I now understand why it diverge, I don't quite understand what you mean(I am not so familiar with English when it comes to math). What do you mean by shifting and adjusting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th term $a_n$ in the series is given by
$$a_n = \left(\frac{n}{-n+1}\right)^n = (-1)^n\left(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n.$$
Thus as $n\to\infty$, we have $|a_n| \to \lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e > 0$.

Comment: gosh, I was overthinking it, I didn't realize..I feel dumb for asking this now :)